How to keep recording the active tab in chrome extension MV3
I am trying to record the active tab with a Chrome Extension MV3, using an offscreen document. It works if I don't switch the active tab, but if I switch I get:
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.

I record the tab with:
async function startRecording(streamId: string) {
  // TODO: Handle tab switch
  if (isRecording) {
    return;
  }

  if (recorder?.state === 'recording') {
    throw new Error('Called startRecording while recording is in progress.');
  }

  console.log("OFFSCREEN: START");

  const media = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
      }
    } as any
  });

in my offscreen document. My Manifest.json has:
"host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "sidePanel",
        "tabCapture",
        "offscreen",
        "downloads"
    ],

I know that the error is thrown for security reasons, and I was wondering if it was still possible to achieve my goal with some permissions.
I could use desktopCapture and choose to record the full browser window at a last resort, but I would like to do it with offscreen document since it records automatically without asking the user what he wants to record
